# Benford's Laws and the digits of PI?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, pi

In the digits of PI themselves there are no evidences that Benford's laws could be manifested.

That is why I decided to conduct the following experiment: I have broken the number PI and its first 1 million digits, in sequences of repeating odd numbers and repeating even numbers, and then added the sum of all the digits in that sequence.

Since single digits are evenly distributed in the digits of PI, I have only included sequences with $2$ digits and above.

What you get is the following (for the first $3.141592653589793238462$):

sequence : sum

31 : 4

159 : 15

26 : 8

535 : 13

8 : (single digit not included)

8 : (single digit not included)

9793 : 28

2 : (single digit not included)

846264 : 30

33 : 6

795 : 21

02884 : 22

1971 : 18

... All the way to the 1 million digit

**I have then searched** to see how many times each single digit number occurred in all the sums (assuming we reassemble all the sums into a large sequence and every digit can act as a first digit in a possible sequence)

**1:** 47981

**2:** 26817

**3:** 6102

**4:** 15534

**5:** 3258

**6:** 14976

**7:** 2943

**8:** 14962

**9:** 3126

(**0** 15035 which is not included in Benford's laws )

I am aware that we are no more directly discussing about the digits of PI, but rather about the sums built from these sequences but it raises my curiosity, and my question is broken in to the following:

A) I understand why there are more even numbers, but it seems as if the gap between an  even number and its following odd number is approximately $* 5$ (slightly less between $2$ and $3$)

Why is that?

B) Even though $1$ is an odd number it still appears much more than all the other even numbers. Also we can clearly see a decrease in appearances, as we progress to the next number (in odd numbers and even numbers separately, and more evidently in the beginning).

It seems as if we could readjust the fact that even numbers occur more than odd numbers, than we would have a 1 appear the most, followed by 2, followed by 3 ...

When comparing to some of the graphs and stats on Wikipedia’s page for Benford’s laws, the results are pretty close looking (similar).

- Update:

From here on I have updated the question following a comment I have received:

"My feeling is there will always be more runs with length two than with length three, more with length three than with length four, and so on, and this will bias things in favor of small digits. Also, a bias for even digits over odd. Of course, this is all based on some randomness assumptions about the digits of π, none of which have been proved." – Gerry Myerson

Back to my updated question: Since there are only theories for Benford's laws, is it possible that Benford's laws in the physical world are manifested because there will always be most 1 pattern digits, following by 2 pattern digits that have more possibilities to begin in 1 (and then by 2...) when adding their sums, following by 3 pattern digits that have more possibilities to begin by 1 (and then by 2...) when adding their sums ....? (Assuming it can be proved that it is the case in the digits of pi)

C) Or are the similarities purely coincidental?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Benford, which has to do with first digits. I think what's happening is this: the most common runs will have length two, therefore, an even sum, giving a boost to the last digit of the sum being even, giving a boost to appearance of even digits. Runs of three even digits should be as common as runs of three odd digits, so no advantage there, but runs of four digits will have even sums, again boosting the appearance of even digits. And so on.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes I understand why there are more even numbers than odd numbers, But the decrease in appearances going down from 1 to 3 to 5 to 7 to 9  and same for 2 to 4 to 6 to 8 ?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson 1 is showing 47981 times. 3 is showing 6102 times and 5 is showing  3258 times

Comment: Runs of length two can only have sum $0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18$ and you can see that $1$ is easily the most common digit there. Runs of length three have sums between $0$ and $27$ and if you look at those numbers you'll see more ones and twos than anything else because they show up so much as the first digit – and there are more ways to get two-digit sums starting with one than with two, so again $1$ has an advantage. And so on.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson so it is unrelated to Benford's Law's but eventually there will be more numbers starting with the digit 1, followed by numbers starting with the digit 2 .....?

Comment: My feeling is there will always be more runs with length two than with length three, more with length three than with length four, and so on, and this will bias things in favor of small digits. Also, a bias for even digits over odd. Of course, this is all based on some randomness assumptions about the digits of $\pi$, none of which have been proved.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I understand why it is caused and why it is not related  but looking on some graphs on Wikipedia’s page about Benford Laws - it is very close looking so far, is there a reason for that ? I also updated that by reassembling the sums into a large number, any digit can act as the beginning of a possible sequence

Comment: "The single digits are evenly distributed in $\pi$". This is true for a huge amount of the first digits of $\pi$ that have been calculated and analyzed. However, we do not know whether this is still true in the long run.

Comment: I would suggest that you generate a sequence of pseudo-random digits and compare whether the results are similar to what you observed in the digits of $\pi$. I guess you get similar results.

Comment: You could probably turn my observations into precise predictions on the relative frequencies of the digits, and then compare what you get to what Benford says. Of course one difference is that the digit zero can show up in your counts, while it can't show up in Benford counts of first digits.

Comment: Benford's law is due to the fact that as the units of measurement (of anything) are arbitrary, the distribution of the first digit must be logarithmic. This has nothing to do with the distribution of the digits in irrational numbers, which tends to be uniform.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I understand but why are the results so similar ?

Comment: I don't understand what you computed exactly. The sum of digits having a uniform distribution is itself non uniform.

Comment: In case anyone might be confused, @YvesDaoust wasn't talking about [logarithmic distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution).

Comment: @Yves Daoust the sums of consecutive odd digits  and the sums of consecutive even digits, which assuming that there are more consecutive 2 digits, followed by 3, followed by 4... . If that can be proved, then we can explain why it is happening, but I just couldn’t ignore the similarities with Benford’s laws which made me curious

Comment: What do you call "similarities" ? Having a nonuniform, monotonic distribution is certainly not enough to declare a similarity.

Comment: @Yves Daoust with your knowledge you are probably right, but for my eyes and my limited knowledge (unfortunately), 1 million digits are enough to confuse me that there are some similarities

Comment: @Yves Daoust I don’t mind the answer to be that these “similarities” are purely  coincidental and not enough to declare a similarity